# Iterate through a list writing to all previous indices

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I'm trying to create a list that holds the coordinates of an object.

```
crds = [0,0,0]
class create:
   line = [["!PlacementError!"] for i in range(0, 8)]
   def lineIterate():
       for i in range(0, len(create.line)):
           print(i)
           crds[0] = i + 0
           print(create.line)
           create.line[i] = crds
           print(create.line)
           print(create.line[i])
```

When I run the code it writes to each index but also all previous indices.

> 0
> [[0, 0, 0], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'],
> ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'],
> ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!']]

> 1
> [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!'], ['!PlacementError!']]
>
> > What is should be:
> > [[0, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0]]

Answer (score 2):

In your code there is only one `crds` list, which you mutate and repeatedly reference in the `line` array. But since it is only one list, when you mutate it, you actually mutate the list that you already assigned to `line[i]` in a previous iteration.

The solution is to create a new list in each iteration, so that `line` will get references to  *separate* lists, not the same one. For instance, you could create a copy on each assignment to `line[i]`:

```
create.line[i] = crds[:]
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! If you don't mind me asking why is the list[:] used in stead of making a new copy of crds per iteration?

Comment: That `[:]` *makes* a copy of `crds` in every iteration. There are many alternative ways of making a (shallow) copy. For instance, `= list(crds)` would also do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you put `crds = [0,0,0]` in `line[0]`, and then you changed the `crds` from `[0,0,0]` to `[1,0,0]`, and you put the **new**(actually not) `crds` to `line[1]`.

you may think that the line should be like: `[[0,0,0], [1,0,0]]`.
Python uses the Shallow Copy, so when you let an element of `line` equal to `crds`, python just created a `link` from the element to `crds`, your `line` is actually: `[crds, crds, crds...]`, when you change element in `crds`, all the element in `line` will be changed.
by using `id()` function you can get the id of the object in python.

```
print('        id of crds:', id(crds))
print('element id in line:',list(map(id,  create.line)))

        id of crds: 2349824066880
element id in line: [2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880, 2349824066880]
```

this may be what you want:

```
class Creat(object):
    """docstring for Creat"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Creat, self).__init__()
        self.line = [["!PlacementError!"]]*8

    def lineIterate(self):
        for i in range (0, len(self.line)):
            self.line[i] = [i, 0, 0]
        print(self.line)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Creat()
    c.lineIterate()

>>> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [6, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0]]
```

or you can use `deepcopy` or `line[i] = crds[:]`:

```
import copy
class Creat(object):
    """docstring for Creat"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(Creat, self).__init__()
        self.line = [["!PlacementError!"]]*8
        self.crds = [0, 0, 0]

    def lineIterate(self):
        for i in range (0, len(self.line)):
            self.crds[0] = i + 0
            self.line[i] = copy.deepcopy(self.crds)
            self.line[i] = crds[:]             # the same as deepcopy
        print(self.line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Creat()
    c.lineIterate()

>>> [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [5, 0, 0], [6, 0, 0], [7, 0, 0]]
```

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. [Shallow and deep copy operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: How would I acces and change the value of a crds list in list after it's creation? Could I write to each one or would I need to create copies of them to that?